# Where is the require.js file generated from?

Tags: javascript, angular, maven, gruntjs

I am learning Angular 2 from this example
https://github.com/pkaul/maven-typescript-example

So after I run the 3rd step (mvn jetty:run), a runnable war folder will get packaged in the example-webapp/target folder. However, there is one file I am not sure about. 
Under folder *example-webapp/target/example-webapp-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/modules*, the **require.js** file, with an old timestamp as 2013-05-14.

I would like to know where it comes from and what it is for. 
I am guessing the file is related to the *requirejs-maven-plugin* plugin defined in the pom.xml inside example-webapp. Standing confirmed or corrected.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.mcheely</groupId>
    <artifactId>requirejs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>optimize</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip><!-- NOT ENABLED AS A DEFAULT -->
        <configFile>${basedir}/src/build/js/optimize.js</configFile>
        <filterConfig>true</filterConfig>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

The file `require.js` is being pulled from a [Maven dependency](https://github.com/pkaul/maven-typescript-example/blob/0.0.1//example-webapp/pom.xml#L28-L33):

> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.jszip.redist</groupId>
>   <artifactId>require</artifactId>
>   <version>2.1.6</version>
>   <type>jszip</type>
> </dependency>
> ```

The project uses the [`jszip-maven-plugin`](http://jszip.org/jszip-maven-plugin/) to handle JavaScript libraries just as if they were standard Maven dependencies (like Spring or else):

> JSZip's Maven plugin is used when you want to either create JSZip modules or consume those JSZip modules in a `war` project.

The big advantage of that plugin is that instead of copying and downloading manually the `require.js` file and putting it in the correct place of your webapp, this makes the build completely automatic and easying updates (you just need to update the dependency). It goes hand-to-hand with the Maven dependency concept for traditional Java libraries.

The plugin will download those JavaScript libraries from [Maven Central](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jszip.redist/require/2.1.6) as `jszip`, [unpack them and put them where configured](https://github.com/pkaul/maven-typescript-example/blob/0.0.1/example-webapp/pom.xml#L40-L70):

> ```
> <plugin>
>     <groupId>org.jszip.maven</groupId>
>     <artifactId>jszip-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>     <extensions>true</extensions>
>     <configuration>
>         <mappings>
>             <!-- copy all JSZIP dependencies to directory "modules" -->
>             <mapping>
>                 <select>*:*</select>
>                 <path>modules</path>
>             </mapping>
>         </mappings>
>     </configuration>
>     <!-- -->
> </plugin>
> ```

In this case, they are copied to the `modules` directory, which is what you see as output. `<select>*:*</select>` means to consider all `jszip` dependencies and `<path>modules</path>` specifies the output directory.

So actually, it has nothing to do with [`requirejs-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/pkaul/maven-typescript-example/blob/0.0.1/example-webapp/pom.xml#L72-L76) which is there to optimize and compress JavaScript files.